# How to sync a async operation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I am currently creating a database util class but my mongodb driver is async, my question now is how can I sync him? My current try looks something like this:

```
public boolean isBanIDFree(String banid) {
    boolean value = false;
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Bans");
    collection.find(new Document("ID", banid)).first(new SingleResultCallback<Document>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(Document result, Throwable t) {
            if(result == null) {
                value = true;
            }
                thread.notify();

        }
    });
    try {
        thread.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return value;
}
```

but I can't edit the veriable value in the onResult Callback, how can I bypass this. i want to return a boolean and want the calling thread to wait until I got the response from the database

Comment: You could use a Semaphore for this.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Would the callback even be called if no document is found?

Comment: Yes it will be called but with e null value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables used in anonymous classes must be effectively final.
That means you cannot assign them to something else, but you can call a setter on them.

So, you can do something like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanWrapper b = new BooleanWrapper();
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> b.setValue(true));
        // ...
    }

    private static class BooleanWrapper {
        private boolean value;

        public boolean getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(boolean value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```